# SpiderMonkey performance measuring tools

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

I have compiled SpiderMonkey from source and i try to measure Execution times of some functions . When i run the code inside Firefox browser using Scratchpad or plain Console session i have tools like : `console.time()` , `console.timeEnd()` , and `performance.now()` . 
This works fine for me , but when i run the code inside SpiderMonkey engine i dont have those tools available , Using `Date()` does not give precise results .

What tools are available inside SpiderMonkey for this type of scenarios  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `dateNow()` function, and there's also [PerfMeasurement object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/PerfMeasurement.jsm) (don't mind the mentions of the jsm code module, the API is directly available in the shell, although only on Linux at the moment).